# Launching Windows VM with having files downloaded and stored on a specific location using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a requirement where I have to launch a Linux VM as well as Windows VM. Linux VM can ONLY be access via Windows VM. I have stored SSH Keys on KeyVault. I want to know if there is a way to download SSH keys from Keyvault and copy files on /.ssh/ folder on the launch of Windows VM from ARM template.

Basically, After the deploy both the VMs, I should just be able to RDP into my Windows VM and should be able to ssh directly to my Linux VM without any further manual work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `Custom Script Extension` for Windows VM which will download SSK key from keyvault and execute your logic.

To check how you can deploy that in ARM template please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#template-deployment).